# locale.getpreferredencoding() - why does this reset string.letters?

Tags: python

```
>>> import string
>>> import locale
>>> string.letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding()
'UTF-8'
>>> string.letters
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Any workarounds for this?

Platform: Linux
Python2.6.7 and Python2.7.3 seem to be affected, Works fine in Python3 (with `ascii_letters`)

Comment: This is certainly weird. I can't reproduce this on Windows (Python 2.7.6), though.

Comment: Can it be related with this bug? http://bugs.python.org/issue11022 I can reproduce it on Linux Mint, python 2.7.5+

Comment: Reproduceable on Mac OS X, python 2.7.5.

Comment: The [`locale` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) mention that a possible side effect of `locale.getpreferredencoding()` is to call `setlocale()`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Note**: what OP did to solve the issue is to pass `encoding='UTF-8'` to the `open` call. If you run into this issue and are just looking for a fix this works. The rest of the post is an emphasis on *why*.

---

#### What happens

As Lukas said, the docs specify:

> On some systems, it is necessary to invoke setlocale() to obtain the user preferences

Initially, string.letters is set to returning `lowercase + uppercase`:

```
lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
letters = lowercase + uppercase
```

However, when you call `getpreferredencoding()`, the `_locale` module overrides it by calling `PyDict_SetItemString(string, "letters", ulo);` after it generates them inside `fixup_ulcase(void)` with the following:

```
/* create letters string */
n = 0;
for (c = 0; c < 256; c++) {
    if (isalpha(c))
        ul[n++] = c;
}
ulo = PyString_FromStringAndSize((const char *)ul, n);
if (!ulo)
    return;
if (string)
    PyDict_SetItemString(string, "letters", ulo);
Py_DECREF(ulo);
```

In turn, this is called in `PyLocale_setlocale` which is indeed `setlocale`, which is called by `getpreferredencoding` - code here http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/07a6fca7ff42/Lib/locale.py#l612 :

```
  def getpreferredencoding(do_setlocale = True):
        """Return the charset that the user is likely using,
        according to the system configuration."""
        if do_setlocale:
            oldloc = setlocale(LC_CTYPE)
            try:
                setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")
            except Error:
                pass
            result = nl_langinfo(CODESET)
            setlocale(LC_CTYPE, oldloc)
            return result
        else:
            return nl_langinfo(CODESET)
```

#### How do I avoid it?

Try `getpreferredencoding(False)`

#### Why does it not happen in windows?

Windows uses different code for getting the locale, as you can see [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/07a6fca7ff42/Lib/locale.py#l593).

#### In Python 3

In Python 3, `getdefaultlocale` does not accept a boolean setlocale variable and does not call setlocale itself as you can see [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d1bf37def4fd/Lib/locale.py#l506).

Comment: In my case I'm triggering this bug due to my code calling `io.open` The fix in my case is to explicitly pass `encoding='UTF-8'` to the call to `io.open`.

Comment: @AnthonySottile yes, that would also work in your case. I was unaware you had a bug and I thought your were just curious :)

Comment: But what might be the reason that you don't observe it when you create a reference to the given objects in the current namespace?

Comment: @devnull python strings are immutable, it swaps the reference.

Comment: Just a quick comment, Python 3 does indeed accept a boolean setlocale variable if you use the same function `getpreferredencoding`. See [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d1bf37def4fd/Lib/locale.py#l629)